# CSS: Input button over background image with gradient

Tags: c#, css, razor

Expected result:

[image: Expected Result]

**Expected and already implemented behaviour: When the camera button is clicked, a file input dialog box opens, and the selected image is displayed on the card.**

What I currently have:

[image: Current Result]

```
<div class="image-vignette flex justify-center items-center px-24">
            <img src="~/images/1.png" id="blah">
            <input type="file"
                id="ImageData"
                onchange="imgPreview(this)"
                asp-for="ImageData"
                name="ImageData"
                style="visibility: hidden"
                accept="image/*" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ImageData" class="text-danger"></span>
            <label for="ImageData">
                <img src="~/images/Camera.svg" alt="camera" class="camera" style="cursor: pointer">
            </label>
        </div>
```

*(the required linear gradients are linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), transparent), radial-gradient(rgba(46, 41, 41, 0.25), transparent))*

Comment: Try experimenting with: `style="position: absolute;"`

Answer (score 1):

The container must have a relative position, and absolute for the child elements which in your case are `label` and `input`. Then you can apply the background you want to these elements (one of them). Avoid using inline styling as much as you can.

```css
.image-vignette{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-vignette .camera{
  max-width: 50px
}

.image-vignette label, .image-vignette input{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  
}
.image-vignette input{
  visibility: hidden
}
.image-vignette label{
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)), linear-gradient(180deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), transparent), radial-gradient(rgba(46, 41, 41, 0.25), transparent);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<div class="image-vignette">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300" id="blah">
    <input type="file"
        id="ImageData"
        onchange="imgPreview(this)"
        asp-for="ImageData"
        name="ImageData"
        accept="image/*" />
    <span asp-validation-for="ImageData" class="text-danger"></span>
    <label for="ImageData">
        <img src="https://www.iconsdb.com/icons/preview/white/camera-xxl.png" alt="camera" class="camera">
    </label>
</div>
```